# Is Heroku worth it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm trying to decide between Heroku and Engineyard.

Heroku seems so much better but they charge for everything and their prices are crazy!

Why one should use Heroku over EY or vice versa?

Comment: Voted to move to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com as this isn't at all programming related.

Comment: You can use Heroku for free until some extent, which is not at all possible on Engineyard. For the few simple Ruby projects I've done, Heroku has been a good match. Of course third possibility would be using JRuby on top of Google App Engine for Java.

Comment: Ditto.  However, the answer is yes it's worth it.

Comment: I tried Heroku and really liked it, especially how easy it was to get up and running with it. However, a deal breaker for me was the "no root access" policy and the fact that there is no JVM installed which I needed for background jobs. So I switched to EY.

Comment: What would you need root access for?  You can always get your own machine on EC2 and connect to it from heroku.  That's really easy to do especially considering they're already based on ec2.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Heroku makes setup and launching of an app super-simple. You will be dependent to some degree on versions that Heroku supports (for instance, I heard today of a bundler versioning issue).

One thing to take into account with any "managed full-stack" solution like Heroku or EY is cost. You don't have to hire an ops person or have ops expertise, but you're still paying. Storage is where things get really expensive. Crank up your DB to a more than a few GB and watch the price go up.

We have in-house ops (was me doing it while coding, now a dedicated person) and run on Joyent. A big cost savings was having a few master-slave DBs and sharing them among a few dozen applications. We essentially have 100 Facebook apps running on Joyent at the same cost as 10 apps on Heroku. But this doesn't take into account the ops salary/time.

Comment: You can share a database across multiple heroku apps now.

Comment: Are you talking about sharing a single database schema? What I'm saying is we have a large MySQL server with dozens of databases running on it. Costs us about $400/month.

Answer (score 15):

Everyone's needs are different, but the great thing is that its easy to experiment with these cloud deployment tools in quick fashion, and you will find that they each have their own strengths that you can leverage as you need.

What is most valuable to me, and my smaller clients, is to be able to experiment and get end-user feedback quickly. I have startup clients that want to be able to push out new ideas and test them quickly, deploy different combinations of ideas to different markets, get customer feedback, and keep moving forward. Launch a facebook app, a test server for an API integration client, a lightweight 'freemium' version of a product, etc. As traffic picks up, we make changes to scale up, and the increase in cost is never out of bounds (eg. our hosting costs are still well under the increase in value/revenue/marketing juice, etc).

EngineYard lets you play around with 500hrs for free, and you can easily turn it off when you are not using it, to stretch the 500hrs out.  You can deploy your app quickly, deploy a CI server (that updates the app on every successful build), create a backup of your app or 'staging' server and see how it goes.

Amazon will give you 750hrs per month for free, for a year, if you are a new AWS customer. You can use this for a super fast CI server, hard-core image processing, batch reporting, whatever.

Personally I happen to use Heroku the most, as it just seems to work the best for my needs. I can put together a new application with full monitoring, backup, analytics, email, etc really fast, and feel confident in how to manage my setup (and confident that I can bring another person on board, and their learning curve will be pretty easy). As a freelancer, my use of Heroku has brought my setup time down to almost nothing, so I'm able to focus my time on understanding the business, and developing a great product. I'm not saying that can't be done on other platforms, I'm just saying heroku is working great for me in that way.

I do have one app that processes Voip data over UDP, so I'll need to figure out if I prefer amazon or engineyard for that (heroku won't let you open a UDP port, as far as I know).

I recently put together [a presentation on these tools](http://www.railsperformance.com/2011/11/cloud-tools-for-rapid-development.html), and how I use them. (it was for newer developers, so it may be too basic for this audience, but there is a list of pros/cons that others may find useful)

Also, I think this conversation does belong here, and not necessarily on a webmasters forum, because the choice of hosting platform will influence your development capabilities and architecture, and the people making the decision are developers, not 'webmasters' or systems people.

Answer (score 4):

I'd vote to use EngineYard over Heroku. Although you can probably deploy a large scale application on Heroku, there's a lot of lock-in you'll have to endure and the pricing can become crippling at higher levels of use.

EngineYard does provide application-level support, too, which is a fair bit better than what Heroku does.

If you're making a quick hobby application or simple demo site, Heroku is great for launching small, simple instances. If you're building a real application where it will need to scale, use EngineYard.

Comment: Can you give an example of Heroku lock-in?

Comment: I don't think it's lock-in, but if you use all their add-on's it makes moving harder because to replicate the functionality you'd have to write a bunch of code.  But... that's what you're paying for.

Comment: All the "add ons" do is handle the configuration for you.  All the ones that I've experimented with end up with the same code, whether you're deploying to Heroku, or you're own target.  But, I haven't used every single one.

Answer (score 4):

We have been running our platform on Heroku for about 9 months, and I am very satisfied.

I think the biggest complaint that most people have is that it gets "expensive" when your site gets large or high traffic. Personally, I think it is much more effective to focus on growing your business or improving your value proposition than maintaining servers or figuring how to get Rails working. (It is no easy task unless you want to spend a lot of time figuring it out). I would much rather pay Heroku to manage the servers for me than hire someone.

Here's what's great about Heroku:

- Pretty easy to use. I didn't know anything about Rails when I got started, and Heroku was simple to get working.
- Good documentation for most things.
- OK tech support.
- Extremely cost effective when you are small.

Heroku is pretty smart, and I am sure they are going to read this, so here's what can be improved:

- Tech support: Typically you ask a question and they respond, and that begs a new obvious question. The tech support person should answer the next question I am going to ask. For example, I might ask how to do something, and then they tell me a certain way of doing it. Now I need information about it. Supply all the information in the first response, so I don't have to ask, "How do I use it?"
- Documentation: Everyone has the same questions. The documentation could be greatly improved by adding all the questions and answers that I have asked, let alone the tens of thousands of other customers.
- Logs: The free logging options are useless, and $100/month for real logs is silly. Our solution has been http://papertrailapp.com which has been outstanding. Use it.

Comment: Logging is now free as of [March 21, 2012](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/11).

Answer (score 2):

I might as well throw my opinion in here since I have **"tried"** to use EngineYard and **"successfully"** use Heroku. While I think both are potentially good choices, I found deploying to Heroku much easier. The ala-carte pricing for Heroku add-ons may add expense, but it also gives you the opportunity to add functionality immediately to your app. The largest expense for our app is the actual web dynos, followed by the database. **Heroku has a great selection of add-ons, many of which are free or low cost.**
EngineYard also seems like a great company but I think they "hold your hand" a little less than Heroku. For my company, the benefits of Heroku outweighed the cost issue. The read-only filesystem which is a platform feature of Heroku also forces you to learn some new tricks.
I now have several apps (small to medium) on Heroku and happily have my assets served up from s3.
**In the end, I would encourage you to try them both.** EngineYard offers a 500 hour trial (though that is computing hours, not necessarily real-time hours) and Heroku let's you get started right away for pretty much free.

**PS:** When selecting add-ons consider your choice carefully, just like when you choose gems for your project. I have experienced an add-on that I was using, simply flaming out and had to scramble to replace that functionality. What was it? Progstr-Filer, which I was using for file uploads. That was a lesson learned.

Answer (score 1):

It depends of the condition. On some case, it's highly expensive

Here we can get a 24 GB o RAM dedicated server for 99 euros.

I can have it set up an running my rail app in less than half an hour, with a mongodb database, as many runner that I want, etc...

Additionally, I can add "small" other project (the ones that costs between 15$ and 35$ monthly at Heroku)

If your business require huge amount of data and processing power, my advice is to use a dedicated hosting and spend the time in managing and monitoring your app.